# Make div's height 100% of parent element with other div children with float

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a row of children elements with equal height. However, the children elements contain images of variable height, so the height should be that of the tallest element. Imagine the following:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"><img /></div>
    <div class="child"><img /></div>
    <div class="child"><img /></div>
    <div class="child"><img /></div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.child {float:left;width:25%}
```

[image: Visual description]
.

I understand this can be done with javascript. However that's out of the question for me (at least I think so) because this is part of an overall responsive design, so the width of the children, while set at 25%, will change with different screen sizes to, say, 50%.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In in the traditional document flow, parents either size their children or are sized by them, they can't normally do both.

That is without flexbox. If you deal with the modern browser requirement, it's the solution you need. http://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback is a good example of how to do these type sizings.

Answer (score 0):

Set child height if you expect these children elements have the same height

```
.child {float:left;width:25%; height: 100px; display: block;}
```

Set max-height for img inside .child

```
.child img {max-height: 100px;}
```

Comment: No, as mentioned it's responsive so the height changes with the width.

Answer (score 0):

Hey now try to this

```css
 *{box-sizing:border-box;}    
.parent{
display:table;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
 padding:5px;
}
.child{
display:table-cell;
  background:blue;
  width:25%;
}
   .child + .child{border-left: 5px solid red;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">demo </div>
    <div class="child">text <br/>demo text</div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child">hello <br/>hello<br/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. As mentioned, there's a float:left in the .child elements. Once you add the float, it no longer work.

Comment: @MikeFeng why are you using float left you just used to display table-cell or table  property if you want to this result .

Comment: Because this is just an example, there are issues in the real case that requires float:left